# ABP/Swashbuckle - Generating swagger docs using Swashbuckle CLI

Tags: abp, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

Using ABP Framework (3.3) and ASP.NET Core (3.1).

I'm attempting to generate swagger.json using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli (https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore#retrieve-swagger-directly-from-a-startup-assembly) after compiling the application, pointing to the compiled dll using the following command:

`dotnet swagger tofile --output "C:\temp\swagger" .\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\MyBin.dll v1`

It gives me the below exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionCommonExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceCollection services)
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Volo.Abp.AspNetCore.Mvc.AbpDataAnnotationAutoLocalizationMetadataDetailsProvider.CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultCompositeMetadataDetailsProvider.CreateDisplayMetadata(DisplayMetadataProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata.get_DisplayMetadata()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata.get_Order()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata.<>c.<get_Properties>b__78_0(ModelMetadata p)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`2.ComputeKeys(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.ComputeMap(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)
   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.ToList()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelPropertyCollection..ctor(IEnumerable`1 properties)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Metadata.DefaultModelMetadata.get_Properties()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadataProviderExtensions.GetMetadataForProperty(IModelMetadataProvider provider, Type containerType, String propertyName)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.CreatePropertyModel(PropertyInfo propertyInfo)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.DefaultApplicationModelProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ApplicationModelProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ApplicationModelFactory.CreateApplicationModel(IEnumerable`1 controllerTypes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.GetDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels.ControllerActionDescriptorProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionDescriptorProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.UpdateCollection()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.Initialize()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.DefaultActionDescriptorCollectionProvider.get_ActionDescriptors()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApiExplorer.ApiDescriptionGroupCollectionProvider.get_ApiDescriptionGroups()
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String documentName, String host, String basePath)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.<>c.<Main>b__0_3(IDictionary`2 namedArgs) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 72
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.CommandRunner.Run(IEnumerable`1 args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\CommandRunner.cs:line 68
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\projects\ahoy\src\Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Cli\Program.cs:line 111
```

I've tried also creating a public class as per the Swashbuckle docs, as we are using Autofac:

```
    public class SwaggerHostFactory
    {
        public static IHost CreateHost()
        {
            return Program.CreateHostBuilder(new string[0]).Build(); //Calls the same builder that's used to run the app
        }
    }
```

The intent is to allow running this in our pipelines to auto-generate ApiClient libraries.

I'm at a bit of a loss as to how to resolve this. The swagger.json is generated at runtime perfectly fine?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

One way to avoid this is to make sure your program continues without these app settings

```
var connectionString = config["MyConnectionString"];
if (connectionString != null)
{
    services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have some appsettings.json (even a default one) - consider changing directory to .\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\ first. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently with 6.4.0 and the cause was due to executing swagger outside of my build directory.

It seems swagger attempts to use the current directory to find dlls that are in use with your application instead of matching the dll directory. If you are running swagger from a higher directory, and point to your startup dll, it wont be able to find any other dependencies.

ex. 1 (DOES NOT WORK FOR ME)

```
PS C:\Project\<ProjectName>: swagger tofile --output Swagger.json .\bin\Debug\net6.0\<ProjectName>.dll
```

**Notice I am currently a few directories above my startup dll**

ex. 2 (WORKS FOR ME)

```
PS C:\Project\<ProjectName>\bin\net6.0: swagger tofile --output Swagger.json <ProjectName>.dll
```

For my build process, I added a powershell script to my project that gets called by the build:

```
param (
    [string]$OutDir,
    [string]$TargetName
)

# Navigate to the output directory to run Swagger
Push-Location -Path $OutDir

# Execute the swagger cli to generate a swagger.json output file based on the executing startup project
swagger tofile --output "Swagger.json" "$TargetName" "v1"

# Return to the original location
Pop-Location
```

In the .csproj you can automate this:

```
<Target Name="GenerateSwagger" AfterTargets="Build">
  <Exec Command="powershell -File $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)Scripts\GenerateSwagger.ps1 -OutDir $(ProjectDir)$(OutDir) -TargetName $(TargetName).dll" />
</Target>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can get the `Swagger.json` in a simple way without Swagger CLI.

**Run your web with the dotnet command:**

```
dotnet  MyCompanyName.MyProjectName.Web.dll
```

[image: Running web]

---

**Then download the `Swagger.json` with the following Powershell command:**

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://localhost:5001/swagger/v1/swagger.json -OutFile c:\temp\swagger.json
```

[image: Downloading Swagger.json]

Comment: As the intent is to use this in a build pipeline, it seems a hacky way to simply generate the swagger json when the Cli package is designed to do exactly what I need.